# regex matching white spaces and non-characters in perl

Tags: perl

I'm looking for pattern matching for the following.
While space at start followed by characters and then a decimal number like 3.2 and then followed by symbols like $ and #.

For ex: " bash-3.2#"

My code:

```
while(@wait = $t->waitfor('/^[\s]bash\-3\.2[.] $/i'))
```

How do i do this.

Thanks,
Sharath

Comment: That's a basic regex that you should be able to do after going through a regex tutorial. What have you tried?

Comment: while(@wait = $t->waitfor('/^[\s]bash\-3\.2[.] $/i'))   But this is not working.

Comment: That code is **very** specific for your example. Are you looking for a general regex, or a regex for your specific example? Also, try editing your question to include your code.

Comment: Have edited the question.

Comment: Your example doesn't match the description of what you want.

Comment: btw, `\2` and `\3`  have special meanings in patterns.

Answer (score 0):

While space at start

```
^\s
```

followed by characters

```
\w+
```

and then a decimal number like 3.2

```
-?\d+\.\d+
```

and then followed by symbols like $ and #.

```
[\$\#]
```

So, something like this:

```
/^\s\w+-?\d+\.\d+[\$\#]/
```

I assumed that the characters are typical word characters and that the number could be negative

Comment: You forget any potential sign character, in case the number is negative.

Comment: It is not clarified in the question, but I will update the answer since it makes it more generalized

Comment: Not in the question, no, but in the example, yes. And, to be honest, I don't know if it's a separation (between characters and number) or number sign, because OP hasn't specified.